# comparing user input with text file

Tags: c++

I doing C++ . I want to compare what is entered by the user in the whole texfile.
My textfile is something like this:

> Kumar India   +9102223403434   01/02/1980  SingaporeAirlines 8118 Elite   -

I have a total of 15 data items. 
And on top of it, the user only has 3 tries if they fail to input the right data.

This is my code. Please advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
void Member();
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int option;
    string member;
    cout<<"\tWelcome!\n";
    cout<<"\n1. Member"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Non member"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter your option."<<endl;
    cin>>option;
    system("cls");
    {
    if (option==1)
    {
        Member();
    }
    else if (option==2)
    {
    cout<<"awesome";
    }
    else
        cout<<"Invalid choice!";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void Member()
{
ifstream inFile;
string userName,userNationality,airline,userType,type,userBirthday,birthday,userContact,Tmiles,userBenefit; 
bool found=false;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
cout << "Enter birthday: ";
cin>>birthday;
inFile.open("list.txt");
if (!inFile)
cout << "Unable to open file"<<endl;
else
{
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile >> userName >> userNationality >> userContact >> userBirthday >> airline >> Tmiles >> userType >> userBenefit;
if (inFile.fail())
    break;
else if (userBirthday == birthday)
        {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"welcome"<< " " << userName <<"!" << endl;
        found=true;
        break;
        }   
}
}
    }
inFile.close();
    if (!found) //found==false
        cout<<"You have exceed the limit. PLease try again"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: My advice is to ask a question. Unless you ask specific questions and describe what is not working for you then you aren't going to get any help

Comment: oh yeah. sorry about it. My issue is that I am not able to compare the user input. Even though I entered in the data that is found in my text file, it just prompt me to enter a different data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that break only exits the innermost loop.

So when you break you exit the while loop but not the for loop, so you get asked again for the birthday.

Change this

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
```

to this

```
for (int i=0; i<3 && !found; i++)
```

Comment: I made the change alr, but it still prompt me for 3 times and end the program even though I've entered in what is in my text file.

Comment: Well time to use a debugger then. Find out what is really happening in your code instead of guessing.

Comment: what is shown on debug: 'PBL.exe': Loaded 'D:\MS6508\PBL\Debug\PBL.exe', Symbols loaded.
'PBL.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'PBL.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'PBL.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
Application "\??\C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" found in cache
The program '[2416] PBL.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).